# Lifetime of Laravel API Authentication token

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

As I've done reading from this link: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/api-authentication

There are questions that I need the answers from someone who has expirienced with this:

- **How long is the lifetime of the generated token?** As I see, token is store in the table `users` with column `api_token`. So I think it might be forever and it may only get generated the first time that it's not exists.
- Can I refresh the token everytime that a user login?

Comment: are you using laravel passport or just build in basic laravel token-based authentication?

Comment: @Theekshana It's just a built in one, not Passport

Comment: 1) if so the token generated by the Laravel doesn't have any expiry time.
2) yes you can refresh the token anytime you want.